# GraphQL, extract all values of a specific type into an array

Tags: graphql

Let's assume I have schema like

```
type StaticData {
    id: Int!
    language: String!
    name: String!
    description: String!
    someA: SpecialType!
    someB: SpecialType!
}
```

`SpecialType` is a scalar. SpecialType can be used in further nested structures as well. Let's now assume  I query for a list of `StaticData`. Is it somehow possible to receive a list of all `SpecialType` values, without me extracting it manually from the returned object?

Example:

My return object looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    language: 'en',
    name: 'Something',
    description: 'SomeDescription',
    someA: 1234,
    someB: 2345
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    language: 'en',
    name: 'SomethingElse',
    description: 'SomeDescription',
    someA: 4564,
    someB: 1234
  },
]
```

Since I want all `SpecialType` values, I do want to extract `[1234, 2345, 4564, 1234]`. Maybe it is possible to do the extraction on the server using resolvers and receive it with the full result object?

Comment: GraphQL, sorry for the confusion

Comment: tech stack - apollo?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible to solve via a query. Since I use Python ariadne, I created a directive, which collects the information and stores it on the context and then one of my Resolver is reading the data from the context. Works well for me!

Comment: it's doable in similar way with apollo @client https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the GraphQL response to be just a list of integers, then you'll need to provide a `type` of that shape to your schema, i.e. `someA: [SpecialType!]`.

You're on the right track - it's on you to then build and return a list in the resolver that satisfies this structure. Hope this helps!